# How to use an imported function as a promise. Object(...)(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following issue.
I have created this function in a separate file

```
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

export default function checkLifeExpectancySet(){
    var decoded = [];
    decoded.permited = [];
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');


    if((accesstoken)){
     var decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
    }
    //if it includes the life_expectancy it means it hasnt been set
    if(decoded.permited.includes("life_expectancy")){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then i call it like this

```
checkLifeExpectancySet().then((result) =>{
          if(result == true){
            //the lifeExpectancy is yet to set
            this.props.lifeExpectancySet(false)
          }else{
            //the lifeExpectancy was already set
            this.props.lifeExpectancySet(true)
          }
        })
```

But it returns

> TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function

I think its an issue because its not a promise or something, how would I convert it in a promise or await for the result? Im lost right now

Comment: If your function is synchronous, why would you need to convert it in a promise?

Comment: Is `Cookies.get` or `jwtDecode` an async function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jwtDecode is not returning promise so, if you want to return promise do this.

```
export default function checkLifeExpectancySet(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

       let decoded;
       const accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

       if(accesstoken){
          decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
       }

       // your other logic.

       // if you want to throw error, uncomment below line.
       // return reject(new Error('some reason'));

       return resolve(decoded);

    });

}
```